# In Xamarin Forms, how do you stop the loading of a WebView on command?

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview

I am implementing browser-like controls on a WebView and am stuck on the reload/cancel button.  If the webview is not actively loading a page, the reload icon is displayed and tapping it will call

```
WebView.Reload();
```

If the webview is actively loading a page, the cancel button is displayed.  I am looking for something like WebView.Stop() to stop the current load, but am unable to find anything like it.

I can not use the navigating event - which is where the button changes from Reload to Cancel - because that completes before the loading starts.  I am looking for a way to stop the process of loading after it has started.

Comment: If you want to cancel current request for wenview, Webview Navigating event, set e.cancel=true can do this.

Comment: As I explained in my question, that cancels the loading before it starts.  I need a way to cancel the loading after it starts, after the Navigating event has already returned.

Comment: I search sone info, but don't find any way to do this, so do you consider to return blank page when you click cancel command?